# ssh session will not close after running remote command

Tags: linux, ssh

i have seen similar questions on the web but none of the answers work, hoping a fresh request will reveal an answer.

i am trying to run a remote query on a linux box which i can do the problem is i stay connected to the remote server.

i have set -x in the script so i am watching the output.
Part of my script is below

```
ssh -tt $host.digital.domain.com << EOF
sudo su - foo
/apps/scripts/bar.sh
exit
EOF
```

the script is runs correctly

```
[user@server ~]$ [foo@host ~]$ + rm -f '/tmp/files*'
```

however the window then gives me the prompt on the remote computer instead of exiting.

```
[foo@host ~]$
```

i used the -tt switch as i was getting the tty error
i have also tried to kill the pid but this doesnt work either.
the only way to progress the script is for me to 'ctrl c' to exit the remote session.

i have tried running ssh it all on one line however this didnt work, possibly due to the sudo, i'm not sure.

Any advice would be great.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

With the "su" command you open new bash session. If you only write one "exit", you only finish the session of foo user. For finished the session open by the ssh connection you should write other "exit".

```
ssh -tt $host.digital.domain.com << EOF
sudo su - foo
/apps/scripts/bar.sh
exit  #Exit foo session
exit  #Exit ssh session 
EOF
```

Output:

```
sshuser@prompt$  sudo su - foo
foo@prompt$  /apps/scripts/bar.sh
foo@prompt$ exit #Exit foo session
exit
sshuser@prompt$ exit #Exit ssh session
logout
Connection to $host.digital.domain.com closed.
```

Comment: Hi fbohorquez, i have tried this an its still retaining the session.   ssh -tt $host.digital.domain.com << EOF
sudo su - foo
/apps/scripts/copy_files.sh
exit
exit
exit
EOF   + rm /apps/scripts/files2copy
+ exit 0
You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/ams
[foo@host ~]$ Killed by signal 2.

Comment: So it has something to do with running the script and the time it takes to complete.                     If the script doesnt need to run then the exit works perfectly --- [user@host1 ~]$ [foo@host1 ~]$ [foo@host1 ~]$ [user@host1 ~]$ Connection to host1.digital.domain.com closed.        However if the script is needed then the session remains open.   [foo@host2~]              so i need to work out a delay between running script and exit command

Comment: You can use "sleep" for delay between running script and exit command. Also you can use "wait" for wait a process is finished. 

Maybe you can use "setsid" for run script in other bash session or "nohup" for don't send SIGHUP signal when exit.