# Running Remote SSH not exiting

Tags: bash, ssh, remote-server

I have to run multiple commands and kind of entire logic to run on remote host from my local laptop (mac m1), here is the simple code

```
/usr/local/bin/sshpass -p mypass ssh -T myid@xyz.com 'bash -s' << 'EOSSH'
checkfunctioncall(){
    cd "/u01/9999"
    mkdir "remotecalltest"
}
checkfunctioncall
exit
EOSSH
```

I tried all kind of combination -T , -t , even passing < /dev/null > /dev/null 2>&1 << 'EOSSH', but nothing works. Issue here is it run's the function and it create directory/ and if it exist it says

mkdir: cannot create directory ‘remotecalltest’: File exists

But, after that it's stuck and not coming out of the session, i have to do CTRL-C, is there a way that it run's entire things like multiple functions and other things and comeout

It should come out of the code, without pressing CTRL-C

Comment: Try adding `-e` to the bash script. That should make it exit if a command fails (like mkdir failing because the directory already exists)

Comment: Is the default remote shell something that's _not_ POSIX-compliant? I don't see why you're using stdin for this at all, as opposed to just passing the code on the command line.

Comment: @Cfreak, mind, `set -e` is less reliable than using `|| return` and `|| exit` as appropriate. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Can you disable your ssh config by executing `ssh -F/dev/null -T myid@xyz.com`. And additionally, run your `bash` with `bash -xs` to see some trace.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ssh session will not close after running remote command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39229686/ssh-session-will-not-close-after-running-remote-command)

Comment: No that won't resolve it

Comment: + checkfunctioncall
+ cd /u01/35220732
+ mkdir remotecalltest
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘remotecalltest’: File exists
+ exit

^C

Comment: but -F did the trick

Comment: Is there something in your .bashrc, .bash_profile, or similar file on the remote system which starts a process running in the background?